# Item with the same ID "860" already exists

Tags: magento2, exception, developer-mode

```
1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "860" already exists.
I am using Magento 2.2.2 .
```

When switched to developer mode, I got this error. I tried searching for solution but found nothing.

**How can I solve it?** Much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs if you delete a product in backend of your shop and some information about its ID is not deleted.

A common source of this error is a duplicate entry in `cataloginventory_stock_item`. You can search for an ID if you have one. If you want to find all duplicate product `entity_id`'s, then simply use this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM cataloginventory_stock_item
WHERE product_id in (
    SELECT product_id 
    FROM cataloginventory_stock_item
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING ( COUNT(product_id) > 1 )
)
```

If it finds duplicates, than you need to **delete** it.

Comment: Thanks but there is no duplicate ID. So how we can resolve this error? See the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/26ekl3i

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin `Marketing > URL Rewrites`

Filter by `category/860` in the `targer_path`, If you find same `target_path` for same store then `delete` the one.

Now Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: You should check for the same `request_path`. There is no problem when two different request paths pointing to the same target_path.

Answer (score 0):

> **Run SQL**

```
SELECT product_id ,COUNT(*) FROM cataloginventory_stock_status GROUP BY product_id, product_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

> **After run above sql you can get all duplicate ids then run below SQL query.**

```
delete from cataloginventory_stock_status where  product_id = {AddDuplicateId} and website_id != 0 ;

update cataloginventory_stock_status set stock_status = 1 where  product_id = {AddDuplicateId} and qty >= 1 ;
```