# My Wishlist add wishlist product all product to addtocart button is not working

Tags: addtowishlist, multiplewishlist

My Wishlist add wishlist product all product to addtocart button is not working
and given error : Item (Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item\Interceptor) with the same ID "1" already exists.

Comment: Have you google it before posting here?
You can refer this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228428/item-with-the-same-id-860-already-exists

Comment: @ankit , the question is different please read it carefully.