when i open the admin panel of magento, then sales>order, then i get the following issue
Issue:
Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "944" already exists.
Exception in /var/www/html/protecta/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:414

are there any customization in order grid?

Try follow this question, same as yours with accepted answer as well. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228428/item-with-the-same-id-860-already-exists

@Bhim Lamichhane
Hey,
It is because of the third party extension override the sales order grid. Please disable third party extension and check.
Thank You!

yes. then i also figure it out.it was from third party extension.. when running sql query it was hitting the join multiple time, causing that issue.so before join i put the condition for join ..it solved my issue
